# Ignore white space after reading csv file tool command line code

Tags: tcl

I am new to tcl programming, I am reading a csv file however the rows can contain a space.  But tcl splits on spaces.  how to ignore that default behavior.
my csv is

```
1,fname,lname 1
2,fname,lname 2
```

The split works, when I try to output `[lindex ${line} 2]` I was expecting `lname 1`.  However since tcl splits on spaces how to I overcome that issue.

```
foreach row $data {
    set line [split ${row} ","]
    puts [lindex ${line} 0]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have the answer right there. When doing *simple* CSV reading, you first `split` by newline to get the records, and then `split` by comma to get the fields in a record.

```
foreach row [split $data "\n"] {
    set line [split $row ","]
    puts [lindex $line 0]
}
```

In the complex case (once you start having fields with embedded commas and newlines and so on) you use the [csv package](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.md) from Tcllib, as that handles the nuances for you. In particular `csv::read2matrix` is helpful.

---

And if you can, use a character other than comma to separate fields. Tabs are a common recommended choice; that makes tab-separated files, and that's very commonly supported and usually has trouble-free interoperation.

Comment: Thanks I am using `csv`  package.  I was unaware of read2matrix, still very new to the language and having difficult time understanding how to use language.